# Minitab question I dont understand how to find the medians for this

Tags: minitab

The question is to analyze a relationship between body size and whether a flea survived the winter or not. The next step is to predict the probability of survival over winter for fleas with body sizes equivalent to the median, first quartile and third quartile of the body size distribution.

How would I find the median value and its respective probability of survival, the first quartile and its respective probability and the third quartile and its respective probability. Use the minitab file I provided.

We used a binary logistical regression model to analyze a relationship between body size and whether a flea survived the winter or not. However, the values we obtained did not make sense and were wrong. I have tried trial and error on this multiple times to no avail.https://kle.keele.ac.uk/bbcswebdav/pid-2666479-dt-content-rid-11161778_1/xid-11161778_1 (The minitab file)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.